# The potential drop in a pn junction diode

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction, circuits

[image]

In the picture shown above, I was trying to learn about diode equivalent circuits. I am not being able to understand the direction of Vb taught by the instructor here. The question is-
If the n region has more potential than the p-region, shouldn't the direction of the battery be reversed.

Comment: No, it looks good to me.

Comment: Would you explain why?

Comment: No, you explain why you think it should be the other way.

Comment: According to me, since the n region has more potential than the p region, it should be the other way.

Comment: Did you forget about \$V_D\$ in your picture?

Comment: Okay, \$V_d\$ is there. So, how does it affect the polarity of the equivalent circuit?

Comment: So, if we have discounted your reason (*since the n region has more potential than the p region*) then what is the alternative explanation? You asked a yes/no question, you didn't say you were going to promote a theory and argue about the truth.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Please explain a bit more directly

Comment: What does the diode symbol in your circuit represent? Why is \$I_D\$'s arrow shown in that direction?

Comment: Try to read this very carefully http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/section3_3Modeling_the_Diode_Foward_Characteristic_package.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is- If the n region has more potential than the p-region, shouldn't the direction of the battery be reversed.

The diode will only conduct one way (ignoring reverse leakage). The diode in your schematic is an 'ideal' diode but real ones require some forward voltage to 'crack' them open. This is represented by the voltage source in your model.

Here's a model discussing an LED rather than your silicon diode but the principle is the same.

[image]

*Figure 1. An LED can be approximated as a resistor with a fixed voltage source. Image mine: ['Resistance' of an LED](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/resistance-of-an-led/).*

LEDs do not have a linear relationship between current and voltage so they cannot be modeled as simply as a resistor using Ohm’s Law, *V=IR*. We can, however, make a simplification and model them over a range of currents as a combination of a resistor and a voltage source.

If we look at a typical LED IV curve we can see that it is approximately linear over much of its useful range. This allows us to model the LED as a resistor and voltage source.

[image]

You might also find the analogy below useful in understanding the diode voltage drop.

[image]

*Figure 3. [The diode check-valve analogy](http://lednique.com/what-is-an-led/).*

See the linked article for more.

Comment: Transistor, If I show your LED equivalent circuit in the picture above to my students, they will be very happy for it because they will now be able to charge their phones for free:)

Comment: I guess I'd better add in an ideal diode. I'll go to the Ideal Diode Shop and get one.

Comment: Well, the good news is that there are people with a sense of humor here:)

Comment: @Circuitfantasist No, Transistor's equivalent circuit is fine. An ideal voltage source is not necessarily a power source. This is exactly how most of the engineers in the world use ideal voltage sources.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, this is only in circuit theory where the source can be not a source; in real life where we are, the source is source producing power and the resistor is resistor consuming power. Every engineer (including Transistor) and technician dealing with real elements and circuits (not only with their abstract mathematical models) imagine the Zener diode as a non-linear (dynamic) resistor forming a (dynamic) voltage divider with another resistor that is supplied by the genuine power source. If you want, think of it as of "constant V" and don't even draw it with this misleading symbol.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist The question is about **circuit theory** so you have agreed with my point.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage is drawn that way, because voltage drops over the diode when current flows. If it were drawn the opposite way, it would make the diode to increase the voltage when current is flowing, and diodes don't do that.

Comment: So you basically mean that the potential drop of 0.7 V for Si is simply the price we have to pay to actually turn on the diode?

Comment: Yes, correct. And if the diode is a green LED, it would have about 2V over it when it is turned on.

Comment: "If it were drawn the opposite way", it would be a "negative diode". The op-amp in the circuit of an "ideal diode" behaves this way - it adds a voltage drop of 0.7 V (VF) in series to the real diode thus making it an "ideal" diode.

Answer (score 1):

Presenting a real diode by a network of two elements in series - an *ideal diode* and *opposite voltage source*, is quite confusing and misleading for beginners. The diode is a passive device that consumes power (subtracts a voltage drop) while the voltage source is an active device in the sense that it injects power (adds voltage). So there is no any voltage source inside the diode.

Also, the IV curve of a passive device should pass through the coordinate origin while the IV curve of the voltage source does not pass through the origin.

This "source diode model" can be used with success if we would like to introduce the dual concept of "negative diode"... or if we want to show how an "ideal" diode can be made. It can be seen in the op-amp circuit of an "ideal diode" where a real diode is connected as a feedback network between the op-amp output and inverting input. The op-amp copies the voltage drop across the diode at its output and then adds this voltage in series to the diode voltage drop. The resulting voltage is (almost) zero and this point is called  *virtual ground*.  Thus the op-amp acts as a "negative diode" and the "ideal diode" is actually implemented as a network of the real diode and op-amp output in series.

The real diode can be most truthfully presented by the concept of "dynamic resistor" that changes its static resistance so that the typical diode IV curve is obtained - Fig. 1.

[image: Diode as dynamic resistor]

Fig. 1. Diode presented as a voltage-stabilizing dynamic resistor

When we turn on the power supply, the (input) voltage VIN increases from zero to maximum. In the graphical representation, its IV curve (including the resistance R) moves to the right (translates). At the same time, the diode begins decreasing its static resistane RST so its IV curve rotates counterclockwise. As a result, the operating point A slides up along the vertical part of the diode IV curve. The current variations are significant while the voltage drop VD (VF) across diode does not change - the diode differential resistance is zero.

This concept should be introduced in the basic courses on Electrical engineering with the purpose to be used lately in the courses on Semiconductor devices. Thus, if students already know what a "dynamic resistor" is, they will easily understand the diode behavior in the vertical part of its IV curve.

So two elements with similar "constant-voltage" behavior should be introduced still in Electrical engineering - *voltage source* and *voltage-stabilizing non-linear resistor*. Then, two dual elements with similar "constant-current" behavior should be also introduced - *current source* and *current-stabilizing non-linear resistor*.

Comment: Your understanding of the ideal voltage source is not correct. An ideal voltage source does **not** necessarily "inject power" or "add voltage" to a circuit. An ideal voltage source **constrains** the voltage between two points in a circuit. It may provide power to the circuit or absorb power from the circuit. If you accept the correct definition then you don't need to concoct a "dynamic resistor".

Comment: In this life, people do not think by definitions. The usual human idea of ​​"source" is like something that produces power (battery). I have not said that this diode equivalent circuit does not work; I said it is confusing and misleading for beginners. From your definition of "source" it turns out that, for example, a Zener diode is a voltage source. So I ask you, "Is it a source?

Comment: In engineering, using words properly is absolutely critical. Correct definitions are absolutely critical. And yes, a zener diode can be modeled, roughly, when properly biased, as an ideal voltage source. Note my careful language: I didn't say that a zener diode **is** an ideal voltage source...that is absurd on its face. But a zener diode **can be modeled as** an ideal voltage source under certain circumstances. These words have meanings and the meanings matter to engineeers. It is your mythical elements that will confuse and mislead beginners.

Comment: My goal is understanding and in the name of this I have introduced these intuitive elements. The difference between the two explanations is that from mine they will understand how the element does it while from yours they will only know what it does. It is much clearer and more understandable to explain how a Zener diode maintains a constant voltage drop across itself by presenting it as a dynamic resistor. I am curious how you will be able to explain it by modeling it with an ideal voltage source. Or will you just tell the poor students that it is by definition so?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I think something you need to try to learn, something I've taken far too long to learn myself, is that the way in which you understand something is not necessarily the way others understand something. What's intuitive to you isn't to everyone, and to me, at least, this explanation of the zener diode as a variable resistor is very unintuitive.

Comment: @Hearth, I agree with you that this is only one of many possible  ways of explaining the diode in an intuitive manner. And what is your way of explaining it? I will be happy to add it to the collection of intuitive explanations ...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist What Elliot is talking about with modeling it as an ideal voltage source is much more intuitive to me.

Comment: @Hearth, OK, I see... and I hope that my explanation will have followers too...