# Ohms law's statement

Tags: resistance, ohms-law

Is this correct:

> "Current is directly proportional to voltage if resistance kept constant"

**V = I*R**

Ohms law is only applied when resistance kept constant or not?

Comment: Ohm's law can also be expressed in this form:$$\text{d}\,V = I\cdot\text{d}\,R+R\cdot \text{d}\,I$$This includes now variations in both resistance and current. You can, if you wish but not necessarily if you don't wish, divide by the infinitesimal of time, so that:$$\frac{\text{d}\,V}{\text{d}\,t} = I\cdot\frac{\text{d}\,R}{\text{d}\,t}+R\cdot \frac{\text{d}\,I}{\text{d}\,t}$$Etc. There are any number of ways of expressing Ohm's Law to achieve specific goals. Calculus provides the always-accurate approach for complicated situations. It never fails you.

Comment: You are not wrong.
If R is constant, Voltage depends on Current.
Higher V will yield higher I, vice versa.

Comment: Resistance doesn't need to be constant to fulfill ohms law.

Comment: @Andyaka look up what Ohm's Law means. It doesn't need constant resistance the way we seem to use it now. However, given the OP's confusion, it's worth making the distinction.

Comment: @Neil_UK are you seriously asking me to look up what ohms law means LOL

Comment: @Andyaka I did, though I'm not sure how authoritative wikipedia is. The numerical bit is easy. The OP's confusion is where and how it's applied. Ohm's law appears to be restricted to Ohmic, ie constant resistance, materials in much the same way that water is a Newtonian fluid, whereas silly putty is non-Newtonian. We don't use it like that now of course, but I try to understand where the OP's confusion could arise, and address that directly in my answers. If there's been a shift in meaning, I like to address it.

Comment: I = V/R. | R = V/I. | V = IR. | All rearrangements of the basic formula. Ohm's law woks for materials whose resistance is independent of current in them or voltage across them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some circuit devices there is a defined relationship between voltage and current. For example, there is an ideal resistor, Where the relationship is the linear one, called “ohms law”. There are ideal capacitors and inductors, the relationship is a simple differential equation.  There are ideal diodes, where the relationship involves exponentials. For some devices, like ideal sources, there are constraints only on voltage, or only on current.

Real world resistors have a more complicated voltage-current relationship than this linear one, although it is seldom important in practice. (But, sometimes it is.)

In summary, ohms law is the voltage current relationship of an ideal resistor, and it is a very good approximation to the voltage current relationship of actual resistors, too.

Comment: For ideal voltage sources and ideal current sources there is **no relationship** between voltage and current...they are completely independent. There really is no "ideal" diode. If there were, it would have no current in reverse bias which again means that voltage and current are completely independent.

Comment: Hi, Elliot: Good points. I guess a more accurate way of saying this is “a description of a component that defines its circuit behavior”. You are right that the  definition of a voltage source does not involve current.   Another term for this is “constitutive equations of the elements”.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your answer.

Answer (score 5):

> Please correct me if I am wrong or like if I define the correct statement. "Current is directly proportional to voltage if resistance kept constant" V=IR

We can find the resistance of a conductor by measuring the voltage across it and the current through it, and taking the ratio.

The statement above therefore is a tautology, a constant proportionality between voltage and current means exactly the same thing as a constant resistance.

> Ohms law is only applied when resistance kept constant or not? Am I right or not?

In its original meaning, Ohm's Law should only be applied to 'Ohmic' materials, that is, materials that exhibit a constant resistance. Materials with non-constant resistance are by definition 'non-ohmic'.

However, common meaning appears to have shifted a little, and we now seem to talk about applying 'Ohms Law' to the process of computing the voltage from the current or *vice versa* given a figure for resistance. Often, resistance is more or less constant, but there are things like filament lamps, whose resistance typically varies over a 10:1 ratio from cold to hot, and thermistors, which are very non-constant.

Given that so few people today recognise the distinction of 'Ohmic' meaning constant resistance, anybody trying to insist on would probably be thought of as a pedant. I prefer to talk about the behaviour of the material, is its V/I ratio dependent on the voltage, on the temperature, on anything else? And then I go and use the term 'Ohms Law' in the present, loose, sense.

Comment: Just to add that in 'modern' circuit theory resistive components are in general nonlinear. A diode is a nonlinear resistor, and so is an incandescent bulb. There are four variables: voltage, current, charge and magnetic flux that are linked in a tetrahedron of 'general nonlinear proportionality' and time differentiation. We  can define four basic (in general nonlinear) components: resistor, capacitor, inductor and memristor. A generalized resistor is a component where voltage depends on the instant value of the current - not its derivative or integral.

Answer (score 2):

Ohm's Law is valid for any part of circuit with no exceptions. Even across non-linear diode we can talk about its dynamic resistance in ohms (you divide voltage by current - note that for non-linear devices resistance is **not a constant**, but Ohm's Law **still works**). You can find diode's power dissipation using Ohm's law - voltage across diode times current through it. Or current squared times dynamic resistance. Or voltage drop squared over dynamic resistance. With Ohm's law you can just substitute them around. But be careful when it comes to what resistance is constant and what can change.

But yeah, if resistance is constant, it's just a factor between current and voltage. You double the voltage - you double the current. Half the voltage will yield half the current.

Comment: No, you are conflating a lot of different concepts here. Ohm's Law says nothing about power. To say that Ohm's Law applies to any part of a circuit with no exceptions is not true...how do you apply it to an ideal voltage source?

Comment: ideal voltage source? How is that a problem? If you short it, you get deivision by zero -> infinite current. So still works. and I'm not mixing it up with power. I'm adding that due to ohm's law P=VI=I^2R=V^2/R. So what exactly is wrong from what I said?

Comment: You said "using Ohm's law - voltage across diode times current through it" suggesting that Ohm's Law talks about multiplying voltage and current. It does not. If you divide the voltage of an ideal source by the current through it you get a meaningless number, not the "resistance" of the source...saying "if you short it" implies that there **is** an exception to your first statement...you can't have it both ways.

Comment: I still don't understand where I'm wrong, your explanation is confusing to say the least. I don't have a single example of ohm's law not working. Even in your example it perfectly applies. Current across perfect voltage source is zero. Resistance is infinity. Perfect match. As for diode, here is the exact confirmation of my words regarding power loss on diode: voltage drop times current. http://www.completepowerelectronics.com/diode-power-loss-calculation/

Comment: No, you are wrong about the ideal voltage source. The current through (not across) can have **any value**. An ideal voltage source has no characteristic called "resistance" because there is no relationship **whatsoever** between voltage and current. Yes, power can be calculated by multiplying voltage times current but that is not part of **Ohm's Law**, it is in fact **Watt's Law**.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Glad there're no ideal source in real life tho. I'll have to look into Watt's law later. Thanks

Comment: @Ilya, I completely second your philosophy. "Dynamic resistance" is a powerful concept for understanding not only well-known nonlinear devices as diodes and transistors... but also weird negative differential resistors (tunnel and Gunn diodes). See, for example, my illustration in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/502755/61398.

Comment: @Elliot, are the power equations Joule's law, not Watt's?

Comment: @Transistor Not sure what you mean by "power equations", but I was taught (and teach) that P=VI is called Watt's Law. See, for example, https://ccrma.stanford.edu/wiki/Introduction_to_Electronics#Watt.27s_Law_.28P_.3D_VI.29

Comment: @Elliot, [Encyclopedia Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/science/Joules-law) says it's Joule's law because he established the relationship betwee P, I and R through experimentation and measurement. James Watt died in 1809 and I don't think he did any electrical work. I suspect that "Watt's law" is just because the result is in watts. It's just a matter of interest. I'm happy to let Stanford carry on in their delusion in peace.

Comment: @Transistor Joule's law has R as a term, Watt's law does not. I will agree with you that it seems odd that the law would be named after Watt.

Answer (score 2):

Ohm's Law states, *'At constant temperature, the current through a conductor is directly proportional to the potential difference applied across its ends.'*

I α V

V/I = R

where 'R' is a constant, known as the resistance of the conductor at that temperature.

The statement, *'Current is directly proportional to voltage if resistance is kept constant.'*, is not Ohm's Law.

Comment: Why is the last quotation incorrect? The constant of proportionality, in this case, is \$\frac{1}{R}\$.

Comment: Hi Chu, Thank you for your question. Apparently I had not conveyed what I had intended to. Hence I have taken the liberty to rephrase my last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

## Preamble

In Germany, we prefer to write Ohms Law as \$U/R*I=1\$, to make the difference between the potential Difference U and its measurement Voltage more clear, but that's besides the point. I also would prefer to use \$i\$ for the imaginary element, but electicians hate that and plug \$j\$ for it... so I will bend to those two.

## Ohms law

Back to the matter. Let's start with adding the other references: G is the measurement of conductivity. A Resistance of a cylinder can be calculated from its specific resistance, the length and the diameter of the item. So, we can expand Ohms Law to this series of quotations:

\$\frac V I=\frac 1 G=R=\rho \frac l A\$

### Altering the resistance?

Now, let's use a simple setup: We put a piece of wire of a known length (1 meter) but unknown composition and diameter into the array between the two clamps of our lab voltage source set to 12 Volts and measure the current. The resulting factor of the measured I and the given 12 Volts gives us the R of our wire, and the factor \$\frac \rho A\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiSwal.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now we alter the length of the wire. Let's say, we shorten it to 0.1 meter, but keep the rest the same. We know, now the Resistance is 1/10th of the previous. Let's also assume, our voltage source stays the same and still puts out 12 Volts. The Factor \$\frac \rho A\$ didn't change, \$l_2 = \frac {l_1} {10}\$, so \$R_2=\frac{R_1}{10}=\frac{12\text V}{I_2}=\frac{12\text V}{I_1 \times 10}\$ Applying some black magic.... and voila: for a changing [length of the] resistance but constant Voltage the current changes by the inverse factor of the change of the length. We can write it as the following, note that \$V_1=V_2\$, so the factor of 1 is technically irrelevant: $$\frac{R_1}{R_2}=\frac{I_1}{I_2}\frac{V_2}{V_1}$$

## Impedance

We see, Ohms Law works for altering the parameters, but that is **DC**. For **AC** the law is to be written slightly differently, as we have permanently alternating voltage and a phase dependence \$\varphi_z\$ of the resistor, which is the result of the phase difference of the Voltage and Current \$\varphi_z=\varphi_u-\varphi_i\$. We talk about the complex value of Impedance now, which has a complex value \$\underline Z\$, and it's associated real value \$Z\$. Though we also know very well that this has to still work for the DC case, where \$\varphi_z=0\$. As a result, we get this relation:

$$\underline Z=Z \times e^{\text j \varphi_z}=R+\text jX$$

\$\text jX\$ is orthogonal to the resistance in the complex room and the reactance, R is the same resistance that we just calculated for the DC-case. So \$\text jX\$ is the imaginary part of the complex Impedance. Because of the geography of the complex room, we can think about this as a vector of the length \$Z\$, which is then rotated around 0 with the angle \$\varphi_z\$. We keep the imaginary part on the sine and voila:

$$\underline Z=Z \times (\cos \varphi_z + \text j \sin\varphi_z)$$
[image: Imaginary room of the impedance]

But, does Ohms law still apply to this? YES, but instead of the DC values, we you plug in the AC case of complex voltage \$\underline u=\hat u \times \text e^{j (\omega t+\varphi_u)}\$ and complex current \$i=\hat \imath \times \text e^{j (\omega t+\varphi_i)}\$, :

$$\underline Z={\frac  {\underline u}{\underline i}}={\frac  {{\hat  u}\times {\mathrm  e}^{{{\mathrm  j}(\omega t+\varphi _{u})}}}{{\hat  \imath }\times {\mathrm  e}^{{{\mathrm  j}(\omega t+\varphi _{i})}}}}=Z\times {\mathrm  e}^{{{\mathrm  j}(\varphi _{u}-\varphi _{i})}}=Z\times (\cos \varphi _{z}+{\mathrm  j}\sin \varphi _{z})$$

Comment: This was the question: "Ohms law is only applied when resistance kept constant or not?" You did not even come close to an answer.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson reread it please: I said it applies even if everything changes and is phased and sinus shaped.

Answer (score -1):

A broader and freer interpretation of Ohm's law today gives us useful functional blocks in circuitry:

Iout = Vin/R (voltage-to-current converter)

Iout = V/Rin (resistance-to-current converter)

Iout = Vin/Rin (voltage/resistance divider)

Vout = Iin.R (current-to-voltage converter)

Vout = I.Rin (resistance-to-voltage converter)

Vout = Iin.Rin (current x resistance multiplier)

A more sophisticated interpretation can give us a good intuitive idea of ​​various dynamic (virtually modified) resistors:

Iout = Vin++/R+ (increased resistance)

Iout = Vin++/R++ (infinite resistance, current stabilzer)

Iout = Vin++/R+++ (N negative resistance)

Vout = Iin++.R- (decreased resistance)

Vout = Iin++.R-- (zeroed resistance, voltage stabilizer)

Vout = Iin++.R--- (S negative resistance)

Here "+" means "increasing", "-" means "decreasing". The number of "+" and "-" represents the rate of change.

The "dynamizing trick" is extremely simple and intuitive... and can be demonstrated only by a variable resistor (rheostat) and a man moving its slider in the according manner. For example, the picture below represents the virtually zeroed resistance of an ideal diode connected in series with a "load" resistor R.

[image: Diode as dynamic resistor]

Fig. 1. Diode presented as a voltage-stabilizing dynamic resistor

When we vary the input voltage VIN, in the graphical representation, its IV curve (including the resistance R) moves horizontally (translates). At the same time, the diode changes its static resistane RST so its IV curve rotates. As a result, the operating point A slides up along the vertical part of the diode IV curve. The current variations are significant while the voltage drop VD (VF) across diode does not change - the diode differential resistance is zero.

It is interesting that all IV curves here are linear including the final diode IV curve in its vertical part. So, we can consider the differential resistance in this part as linear and define it with large-signal quantities.

The differential resistance is something like an illusion created by the self-varying static resistance RST. This "illusion" acts while the static resistance RST changes as shown and its iV curve rotates. If at some point we fix RST, the IV curve will stop rotating and the operating point will begin moving along the sloping IV curve of the current static resistance (not along the vertical line of the differental resistance as before). Both current and voltage will vary as in the case of an ordinary ohmic resistor... and the magic of *dynamization* will disappear...

See also a related [Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Negative_Differential_Resistance).